# Dealing with trichotomy laws in arguments requires the Proof by Contradiction methodoloy?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I recently carried out a proof that required me to invoke the law of trichotomy on $\mathbb R$ in order to progress my argument. I found that two of the three cases led to contradictions, so I casually concluded the 3rd option must be the valid case. After completing my overall argument, I mulled over whether *this* aforementioned step was actually an instance of applying two "mini" versions of a proof by contradiction.

Here are my thoughts:

---

Firstly, I assume that the notion of proof by contradiction written in the form of sequent calculus in the context of classical logic, where *Law of Excluded Middle* is in effect, can be written as:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\neg A &\vdash \bot \\
\hline
&\vdash A
\end{array}
\quad\quad(\dagger)$$
If this is correct, then I'd like to generalize my description from my first paragraph as:

$$\Gamma \vdash (P \land \neg Q \land \neg R) \lor(\neg P \land Q \land \neg R)\lor(\neg P\land \neg Q \land R)$$, where the disjunction on the right side is capturing the logical features of the trichotomy rule. (For the sake of argument, let's say that $R$ was the formula that I ultimately proved must be the true one)

Next, I believe I carried out these two steps:

1A)

\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma, P \land \neg Q \land \neg R  &\vdash \bot \\
\end{array}

1B)

\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma, \neg P \land Q \land \neg R  &\vdash \bot \\
\end{array}

Applying $(\dagger)$ to each of these sequents, I get:

2A) $\vdash \neg \Gamma \lor (\neg P \lor Q \lor R) $

2B) $\vdash \neg \Gamma \lor ( P \lor \neg Q \lor R) $

At this point, when I *assume* $\Gamma$, I effectively conclude:

$\Gamma \vdash (\neg P \lor Q \lor R) \land ( P \lor \neg Q \lor R)$, which means $\Gamma \vdash R$ because $[[(P∧¬Q∧¬R)∨(¬P∧Q∧¬R)∨(¬P∧¬Q∧R)]∧[(¬P∨Q∨R)∧(P∨¬Q∨R)]]→R$ is a tautology.

Is this essentially correct? If so, then I clearly employed the method of proof by contradiction, yes?

---

I raise this point because I have seen people ask questions of the form: "I want to prove this statement constructively and not use proof by contradiction". In the proof that I previously alluded to, I carried out what I originally thought was a constructive proof. This "constructive" proof contained, as one of its subarguments, the previously described methodology of handling the different cases posed by the trichotomy rule. Given this, I subsequently wondered if my proof would qualify as constructive.

---

**Edit**: In retrospect, it seems that my $\dagger$ would have been more appropriately encoded as:

$$
\begin{array}{c}
A &\vdash \bot \\
\hline
&\vdash \neg A
\end{array}
\quad\quad(\dagger)$$

, which is an instance of $(\rightarrow I)$, and therefore, this overall approach made no use of the excluded middle (nor a proof by contradiction). Instead, this was a **proof by negation**

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for calling this out. It was just an intuitive claim at first, but after working it out, I believe the following is a tautology:

$$\left[\left[(P \land \neg Q \land \neg R) \lor(\neg P \land Q \land \neg R) \lor(\neg P \land \neg Q \land R)\right] \land \left[(\neg P \lor Q \lor R) \land (P \lor \neg Q \lor R)\right] \right]\rightarrow R$$

You'll recognize those antecedents as the trichotomy rule and the conjunction that the contradictions gave us. I think this is correct...hence, $\Gamma \vdash R$

Comment: Do note that if the trichotomy law is referring to $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, (x < y) \lor (x = y) \lor (x > y)$, that itself is usually not considered a valid law in a purely constructive setting.

Comment: @DanielSchepler what variant of the law do constructivists use?

Comment: It really depends on the situation, I think.  But mostly, I would say that probably, about the closest you would get would be something like: if you expand $x$ and $y$ to some level of precision, either you can find that definitely $x < y$, you can find that definitely $x > y$, or the test is inconclusive if $x$ and $y$ are close enough.  You might also get something like: for any precision level $\varepsilon > 0$, either $x < y + \varepsilon$, $x > y - \varepsilon$, or $|x - y| < \varepsilon$ (with possibly more than one holding).

Answer (score 2):

"[Proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction)" is ambiguous from a constructive point of view.

We have [Trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)):

> $x=a ∨ x<a ∨ x>a$,

whose logical form is: $P \lor Q \lor R$.

The structure of the proof is to show that if two of the cases do not hold, then necessarily the third will do. In formula:

> $\Gamma, (P \lor Q \lor R), ¬P,¬Q \vdash R$.

Working with Natural Deduction, we have two nested Disjunction Elim: $P \lor (Q \lor R)$.

Assuming the first disjunct with $\lnot P$ we derive $\bot$ and thus $R$. The same with $\lnot Q$.

The last case obviously implies $R$.

Thus, we can close the two nested sub-proofs to conclude with $R$.

---

In conclusion, we need [Ex falso](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4): $(\bot \text E) \ \ \bot \vdash \varphi$ but not DNE: $"\text {if } \lnot \varphi \vdash \bot, \text { then } \vdash \varphi"$, which is equivalent to LEM.

From a constructive point of view, the rule: $"\text {if } \varphi \vdash \bot, \text { then } \vdash \lnot \varphi"$ is simply $(\to \text I)$, and does not imply DNE.

---

---

As per Daniel's comment above, one thing is *to prove* trichotomy, and another is *to use* it.

Comment: After looking at my post, it seems like it would have made more sense to write my $\dagger$ as:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
A &\vdash \bot \\
\hline
&\vdash \neg A
\end{array}
\quad\quad$$

, which, as you've stated, is actually an application of $(\rightarrow I)$

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by the phrase, "Assuming the first disjunct: $(¬P∧Q∧¬R)∨(P∧¬Q∧¬R)$ with $\lnot Q$ and $\lnot P$ respectively..."? I read that as $\Gamma, (¬P∧Q∧¬R), \neg Q \vdash \bot$ and $\Gamma, (P \land \neg Q \land \neg R), \neg P \vdash \bot$. If that is the correct interpretation, I'm not sure *why* we are assuming $\neg Q$ and $\neg P$

Comment: @S.Cramer - "trichotomy" is symmetric; thus, the gist of the proof is to show that if two of the cases do not hold, then necessarily the third will do. In formula: $\Gamma, \lnot P, \lnot Q \vdash R$

Comment: I guess I am a little confused at what point your method shows $\Gamma \vdash \neg P$ and $\Gamma \vdash \neg Q$. We would have to show this first, right?

Comment: Sorry if there was ambiguity in my prompt. The premise of this question was based off a proof I used. In that proof, I ultimately demonstrated that some object $x$ needed to be greater than some object $a$. I did this by showing that both $x=a$ and $x \lt a$ produced contradictions. Informally, we say that the trichotomy of reals is represented by the statement $x=a \lor x\lt a \lor x \gt a$.

Comment: However, because it is impossible to for $x$ to simultaneously occupy more than one of these conditions (e.g. $x=a \land x\lt a$ is nonsense), I assumed the proper way of writing this was: $\left(x=a \land x \not \lt a \land x \not \gt a\right) \lor \left( x\not=a \land x  \lt a \land x \not \gt a\right) \lor \left(x\not=a \land x  \not\lt a \land x \gt a\right)$.

Comment: Placing my question in the context of this example, when I wrote, "for sake of argument, let $R$ be the formula that was ultimately proven to be true", what I was trying to replicate was that I demonstrated $x \gt a$ was true. So, perhaps I should have said, "for the sake of argument, let $(\neg P \land \neg Q \land R)$ be the formula that was ultimately proven to be true". My goal was to then show that, if I can demonstrate that assuming the *other* disjuncts (one at a time) each leads to a contradiction, I will formally derive why I can conclude $\Gamma \vdash (\neg P \land \neg Q \land R)$

Comment: From which I believe I can directly conclude: $\Gamma \vdash R$.

Comment: @S.Cramer - Ok; simplify my proof above. You have trichotomy available: $x=a ∨ x<a ∨ x>a$ and you have proved that $\lnot (x=a)$  and $\lnot(x<a)$. So you have the "axiom" $P \lor Q \lor R$ and you have proved $\lnot P$ and $\lnot Q$. Apply the proof strategy above to conclude with $R$.

Comment: From a propositional point of view, we need only $(P \lor Q \lor R)$ to model trichotomy because $\lor$ is commutative and associative and thus we can swap the three cases.

Comment: So, using the simplified disjunction that does not involve conjuncts, the last stages of the argument (once we've shown that $\Gamma, P \vdash \bot$ and $\Gamma, Q \vdash \bot$) amounts to:

\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma \vdash \neg P \quad \Gamma\vdash \neg Q \quad \Gamma \vdash P \lor Q \lor R \\
\hline
\Gamma \vdash R
\end{array}

I assume that's the gist of things?

Comment: where this inference would effectively stem from the fact that $\Gamma, \neg R \vdash \bot$ ...because $\neg P \land \neg Q \land \neg R \land (P \lor Q \lor R)$ is a contradiction.

Comment: although, it seems like this final inference rule is employing the double negation law (at least through the way that I justified it). Any input is greatly appreciated. Cheers~